# When is $(a+b)^n \equiv a^n+b^n$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finite-fields, equivalence-relations, binomial-theorem

I remember a relation like $(a+b)^n \equiv a^n+b^n$, but I don't remember mod which numbers this is true.  Where can I learn more about this?

Comment: If $n$ is a power of a prime $p$ then the congruence holds $\pmod{p}$. See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/504748/theorem-regarding-greatest-common-divisor-of-certain-binomial-coefficients).

Comment: (a + b)^n = a^n + b^n (mod ab)

Comment: Try expanding $(a+b)^{n}$.

Comment: Also, unexcitingly, for $n=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Fermat's Little Theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) states that:

For any integer $k$ and any prime $p$, we have $k^{p} \equiv k \mod p$.

Suppose $p$ is prime, and we have integers $a$ and $b$.

If you consider $k = a + b$, which is still an integer, then the above says:

$(a+b)^{p} \equiv a+b \mod p$.

Note also that $a^{p} \equiv a \mod p$ and $b^{p} \equiv b \mod p$; so $a^p + b^p \equiv a + b \mod p$.

Combining the previous two lines yields your equivalence:

$$(a+b)^{p} \equiv a+b \mod p \equiv a^p + b^p \mod p$$

**Note 1:** Sometimes one uses a fact like the one in your question to *prove* Fermat's Little Theorem; this is not the only proof, but do be sure that you don't find yourself reasoning circularly!

**Note 2:** It is not too hard to conjecture that Fermat's Little Theorem yields equivalence for prime exponents. We can even check the first couple of cases by hand. Let $n$ be an integer.

$p = 2$: This says that $n^2 \equiv n \mod 2$, i.e., $2$ divides $n^2 - n = n(n-1)$, which is clearly the case: The product of two consecutive integers must be divisible by two, because one of them is even!

$p = 3$: This says that $n^3 \equiv n \mod 3$, i.e., $3$ divides $n^3 - n = n(n^2 - 1) = (n-1)n(n+1)$, which should also be clear: Any three consecutive integers has one of them divisible by three, and so their product is divisible by $3$.

$p = 4$: This says that $n^4 \equiv n \mod 4$. But this is false already for $n=2$.

$p = 5$: You can work this one out with a bit of factoring and some case work, and then find another counterexample for $p = 6$. At that point, you may conjecture that for $p > 1$, Fermat's Little Theorem holds only at the primes.

Answer (score 5):

This is sometimes called the *beginner's binomial theorem* or *[Freshman's dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman's_dream)*.  It holds in fields of characteristic $n$, which only exist if $n$ is prime.

It holds in particular modulo $n$ (for $n$ prime) because most of the binomial coefficients are divisible by $n$ in this case, so modulo $n$ they all vanish and the binomial formula simplifies to $$(a+b)^n = \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i} a^i b^{n-i} = a^n + b^n \mod n.$$

Note that if $n$ is not prime, the statement about binomial coefficients is not true.  For example $\binom{4}{2} = 6$ is not divisible by $4$.