# $(a+b)^n=a^n+b^n$ in a field of characteristic $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra

There is a theorem :
In a field such that its Characteristic $n$ is greater than zero , the equality $(a+b)^n=a^n+b^n$ is true.

Does anyone know how to prove it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Try the binomial theorem

Comment: Yes, the binomial theorem and the fact that $n$ must be prime to be a non-zero field characteristic.

Comment: Related (duplicate?) [When is $(a+b)^n \equiv a^n+b^n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1409017/when-is-abn-equiv-anbn)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman's_dream

Comment: The binomial theorem only applies when $a$ and $b$ commute.  @orel You originally indicated that your question was about linear algebra, are $a$ and $b$ supposed to be matrices?

Comment: You might check out https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3135077/x-mapsto-xp-with-operatornamecharf-p0-is-a-ring-homomorphism

Answer (score 1):

In a field the characteristic $n=p$ is prime and the result follows from the fact that
$$
p\mid{p\choose k}=\frac{p!}{k!(p-k)!}
$$
if $0<k<p$.

On the other hand in a ring that it is not generally true. For instance in a ring of characteristic $4$ we have
$$
(a+b)^4=a^4+2a^2b^2+b^4
$$
identically.

Comment: Did you mean $1 \mathbf \le k$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, thanks for pointing out the typo. I edited the answer.